# Background color for text (only)

Tags: css, text, background

I am wondering if it's posible to achieve this:

[image]

I mean, applying the background color just to the text instead of the whole block,

ej

```
<h1>WELLCOME TO RENTAL IN MALLORCA BEATYFULL COLLECTION OF APPARTMENTS</h1>
```

Is there a (cross browser, if possible) way to do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes. Add a `<span>` inside the `<h1>`, and apply the background colour and a line-height to it.

```css
h1 {
  width: 250px
}

h1>span {
  background-color: yellow;
  line-height: 2
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Testing, testing, this is a really long piece of text blah blah blah Hi there!</span></h1>
```

Comment: In order to get the exact replica though, you will need to add span to each line break, in Kolink demo its one line with a span, but in your image each has padding to the left, and right.  This can only be accomplished by adding span. For example. span welcome to /span

Comment: Can't we do this without adding span?

Comment: Yes w3debugger, you can set the h1 to display inline so you dont need to use span.

Answer (score 19):

In addition to Niet's answer:

to get extra space (here 10 px) on the left and right side of every line add this to the span:

```
h1 span {
  box-shadow: 10px 0 0px 0px #EDC330, -10px 0 0px 0px #EDC330;
}
```

Comment: Nice touch! I also added padding: 10px 0; to the span to  give a little extra space above and below the text.