# How to properly highlight text in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, flexbox

I would like to highlight a multiline text in a React Native app by changing the text's background color. The problem is that the background color changes in the whole text area, not just under the words.

```
class Example extends Component {
  render() {
    const text = '...';

    return (
      <View style={styles.textContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
          {text}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    width: 200,
  },
  textStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
});
```

The code above results in something that looks like this: [image: current output]

But I would like it to look like this: [image: expected output]

I can get that result by splitting the text and adding the background color to the individual words:

```
class Example extends Component {
  render() {
    const text = '...';

    const brokenText = text.split(' ').map(word => (
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{word} </Text>
    ));

    return (
      <View style={styles.textContainer}>
        {brokenText}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

But splitting the text into individual words doesn't seem like the best solution, and has a huge performance cost. Is there any cleaner way to do it?

Comment: have you tried using something like a text-shadow? I'm not sure what the react native equivalent would be

Comment: @Felipe textShadow has a different look (it's a blurred shadow under the text), and doesn't really work well for highlighting the text :/

Comment: true, I was thinking maybe with some hacky usage but it didn't work out. what about if you split by new line instead of by character, similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597304/background-color-for-text-only

Answer (score 6):

This is still not proper but I had it rendering as you expect by adding an invisible character (no-width space here) between each word, so the text breaks on it which has no background color. Here is the code :

```
const NO_WIDTH_SPACE = '​'; // This is a special char you should copy and paste, not an empty string!

const Example = () => {
  const highlight = string =>
    string.split(' ').map((word, i) => (
      <Text key={i}>
        <Text style={styles.highlighted}>{word} </Text>
        {NO_WIDTH_SPACE}
      </Text>
    ));

  return (
    <Text>
      Some regular text {highlight('with some properly highlighted text')}
    </Text>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  highlighted: {
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
  },
});
```

**Here is a Snack where you can see the result and play with it :** https://snack.expo.io/@adesurirey/properly-highlight-text-with-react-native
[image: Snack preview]

It can surely be improved, I'll be happy to have feedback.

Answer (score 1):

**Here i have done you can look.**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const array =["Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone! and fine."];
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
        {array.map(t=> (
            <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{t}</Text>))}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingTop: 50,
  },
  paragraph: {
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  },
});
```

Comment: @Bruno Brugger Please upvote and tick the answer. if it help you in order to help me.

Comment: It still highlights until the end of the lines (only the last one ends at the right place). I think the inner Text (where the backgroundColor is set) wraps around the same way as if it was just one Text component :/

Answer (score 1):

Try using

[react-highlight-words](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-highlight-words) library which can meet your need or use [react-native-highlight-words](https://github.com/clauderic/react-native-highlight-words) library.

Both of these libraries are derived from the node package [highlight-words-core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highlight-words-core)

Answer (score 0):

This simple function with Lodash

```
  const highLightWord = (word, highlight) => {
    const match = _.words(word, RegExp(highlight)); // "Aku"
    const notMatch = _.replace(word, match, ""); // "rana"
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <Text style={{ backgroundColor: "yellow" }}>{match}</Text>
        <Text>{notMatch}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

```
return (
 {highListSearch("Akurana", "Aku")}
)
```

Answer (score -3):

I believe the issues is the `display` css property on your component.

Your component seems to be rendering with `display: block;` instead of `display: inline;`

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/oorangecchicken/2qkey6o9/

Comment: I think React Native doesn't support inline display (only flex). The closer I could get is the flexWrap property, but it doesn't seem to do exactly the same thing